# ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset. (Tensor Flow DNN model on Colab)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I am trying to use a DNN to predict customer lifetime value. I have followed [this blog post](https://antonsruberts.github.io/DNN-for-CLV/). I am running into an error when I run the code for fitting the DNN model to my dataset. I am pretty new to machine learning and I have tried to do due diligence in understanding what the code is doing.

```
#DNN
def build_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(X_train.columns), ]),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
    ])

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)

    model.compile(loss='mse',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
    
    return model

# The patience parameter is the amount of epochs to check for improvement
early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=20)

dnn_model = build_model()
early_history = dnn_model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    epochs=1500, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0,
                    callbacks=[early_stop, tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots()])

#Predicting
dnn_preds = dnn_model.predict(X_test).ravel()
```

The error happens on the callbacks parameter. I understand that the callback is to stop the model from training, given that the loss metric being monitored can no longer be minimized.

I have gone around so many sites to ascertain why the error flags but I have kept on coming up short. any help rendered will be appreciated.

The error code is shown below.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-317a4345770f> in <module>()
     22 early_history = dnn_model.fit(X_train, y_train,
     23                     epochs=1500, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0,
---> 24                     callbacks=[early_stop, tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots()])
     25 
     26 #Predicting

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1108 
   1109         if logs is None:
-> 1110           raise ValueError('Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.')
   1111         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
   1112 

ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `X_train` is empty. Can you add how you load `X_train`?
(Python's Tracebacks point to the function call when the error was raised, not to a parameter).

Comment: Ok, that gives me clarity but this is weird because I use the same X_train to fit a linear regression model just earlier. When I hover over X_train in 

`dnn_model.fit(X_train, y_train,
     23                     epochs=1500, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0,
---> 24                     callbacks=[early_stop, tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots()])`

It shows me a data frame with shape 3510, 11.

I am happy to share the link with you to take a look, or am I missing something when you say "How I loaded" X_train